# MySQL. Verifying Integrity of Restored Databases

Tags: mysql

What are the best tools/methods for verifying integrity of restored databases?
Our planned backup process looks like this:

1. Master server sends data to Slave server.
2. MySQL Server process on Slave server gets shut down.
3. Azure Site Recovery takes file-system level backup.
4. Another VM is created from that backup.
   How can we verify that databases on step 4 are consistent with databases on Master server in step 1?

All VMs are on Windows Server.

Comment: If there was no errors during the whole process then there is no reason for inconsistency.

Comment: I don't think no errors approach as good enough. I'd like to reliably verify that restored databases are consistent with source databases.

Comment: And how do you want to do it if source database was changed during the backup timepoint?

Comment: That's what this question is for.

Comment: In general I cannot see the solution. If you need to test the copy for full matching then you must have full DB snapshot for to compare with. But MySQL does not support data versioning and time tracking. The only solution I see is: disable user access to master and flush data, sync it with slave, stop replication and use slave's database as a snapshot for comparing. If slave is created for making the copy only this is safe, if not I'd recommend to create one more slave - for snapshot storing and matching test only.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like exactly what we're looking for! Creation of another slave is mentioned in step 4. Any tools or mysql commands that can implement such solution?
This tool looks interesting https://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/verifying-mysql-replication-integrity-pt-table-checksum-percona But it's only Linux based, and we are on Windows.